# Issue with custom fonts in TextView and WebView

Tags: android, webview, textview, android-typeface

There is an issue with English text in TextView and WebView when using Arabic or Persian typeface, The following image is an example of Persian and English text in both TextView (2 views in the header) and WebView (at the bottom) when using default typeface : [Shot 1](http://uupload.ir/files/i5ry_screenshot_2015-07-05-18-03-16.png)

But when applying a custom typeface it looks like this (Iran Sans Serif is applied here but almost all Persian fonts have the same issue) : [Shot 2](http://uupload.ir/files/ow2q_screenshot_2015-07-05-17-59-55.png)

As you can see, in TextView with Persian typeface, English texts are not aligned correctly and in WebView there is extra padding between some lines due to difference between Persian texts size and English texts size.

Be sure that there is no problem with the fonts because in Websites, they're working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
<style name="TextViewFont" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/sogand</item>
</style>
```

```
<TextView
            style="@style/TextViewFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="5"
            android:shadowDy="5"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:text="@string/mahyar_school"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```